# UIStoryBoard Navigation Controller disappearing after segue

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Reference layout via storyboard:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQa10.png

Reference landing page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9sCo.png

I am trying to use the bottom bar as displayed in picture 2 to control my app. When I select my option on the first page (Such as the songs tab), but when I go to the next page my navigation bar at the bottom disappears. I am using segues to direct my applications view flow.

I have tried making various controllers subclassed to a UITabBarController & pushing as modal. Neither of those kept the navigation controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have that navigation controller as the initial controller, the tab bar controller should be first. Then, in each of the three tabs, the root view controller should be a navigation controller, followed by the ones you show in your image.

Comment: What do you mean root view controller? How do I set that? I deleted my navigation controller and made the tab bar controller the new initial controller

Comment: @RyanCopley, I mean the controller that's connected to the tab with a relationship segue. You can just select a view controller that's now connected to your tab bar controller, and go to the Editor menu and choose embed in navigation controller. That will insert a navigation controller in between the tab bar controller and the one that was previously attached to the tab bar controller.

Comment: Sorry for taking a few days to get back, I managed to get it working! Thanks a lot bud!